# Eslint - How to Indent Import Export Statements

Tags: javascript, formatting, indentation, eslint

I just upgraded my Eslint after a long time and all of a sudden, I have a lot of errors. Of note & issues raised below is `indentation`. Maybe its worth mentioning that I use `tabs` instead of `spaces` for my indentation

**Problem:**
My import values are indented as per the eslint indentation terminology "first". "first" basically means, all additional declarations are indented to align with the first property. See this:

[image]

**Solutions I tried:**
Here is what my indentation rules look like within '.eslintrc' file:

```
"indent" : [ 1, "tab", {
    "FunctionExpression": {
        "body": 1,
        "parameters": "first" },
    "VariableDeclarator": {
        "var" : 2,
        "let" : 2,
        "const" : 3
    },
    "MemberExpression": 0,
    "FunctionDeclaration": {
        "parameters": "first" },
    "ObjectExpression" : "first"
}],
```

Even though I am using `tab`, not `space` for indetation, I still had to use the `VariableDeclarator` rule above to align all the vars/lets/constants etc. However, `import` & `export` are still flagged up and I cannot find any rule which resolve these indentations. So, how do I indent import/export statements?

Answer (score 1):

There has been some work for this enhancement to `indent` rule. Please follow the conversation here: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/pull/8955

Comment: I see it merged in Aug, however, in my eslint v4.9, I continue to get the warnings : "expected indentation of 9 tabs instead of 3". I do have the rule `"ImportDeclaration" : "first"` in my eslintrc file.