# ESlint indent import / export statements

Tags: webstorm, eslint

I'm using [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm) as IDE which supports the following formatting-option to [indent import / export statements](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/settings-code-style-javascript.html#ws_js_settings_editor_code_style_wrapping_and_braces_tab).

> The corresponding option can be found in: 
>   *File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > JavaScript > Wrapping and Braces > ES6 import/export*

The result, if option checked, is:

```js
import {Dropdown}     from '../drop-down.ts';
import AwesomeLibrary from 'library';
import * as core      from 'core/all';
```

As we can see, each `import` statement is aligned with the longest one, in this case `import AwesomeLibrary from 'library';`.

The same counts for `export` statements:

```js
export *          from './lib'
export foo as bar from './hello'
```

I only found out about the rule [`indent.ImportDeclaration`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent), added in [this PR](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/pull/8955) and mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45403915/eslint-how-to-indent-import-export-statements) question. But this rule only handles indentation in these import statements:

```js
import {
  Foo,
  Bar,
  Baz
} from 'lib'
```

Is there a rule available to achieve the previously mentioned kind of intention / formatting?

Answer (score 1):

I've wrote an [plugin](https://github.com/Simonwep/eslint-plugin-align-import) to do that.

```sh
$ npm install eslint-plugin-align-import --save-dev
```

And in your `.eslintrc`:

```
{
    "plugins": [
        "align-import"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "no-multi-spaces": ["error", {"exceptions": {"ImportDeclaration": true}}],
        "align-import/align-import": "error"
    }
}
```

The `no-multi-spaces` has to be turned off for import declarations.